# Regex: Matching against groups in different order without repeating the group

Tags: regex

Let's say I have two strings like this:

```
XABY
XBAY
```

A simple regex that matches both would go like this:

```
X(AB|BA)Y
```

However, I have a case where A and B are complicated strings, and I'm looking for a way to avoid having to specify each of them twice (on each side of the |). Is there a way to do this (that presumably is simpler than having to specify them twice)?

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
X(?:A()|B()){2}\1\2Y
```

Basically, you use an empty capturing group to check off each item when it's matched, then the back-references ensure that everything's been checked off.

Be aware that this relies on undocumented regex behavior, so there's no guarantee that it will work in your regex flavor--and if it does, there's no guarantee that it will *continue* to work as that flavor evolves.  But as far as I know, it works in every flavor that supports back-references. (EDIT: It does not work in JavaScript.)

**EDIT:** You say you're using named groups to capture parts of the match, which adds a lot of visual clutter to the regex, if not real complexity.  Well, if you happen to be using .NET regexes, you can still use simple numbered groups for the "check boxes".  Here's a simplistic example that finds and picks apart a bunch of month-day strings without knowing their internal order:

```cs
Regex r = new Regex(
    @"(?:
        (?<MONTH>Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)()
        |
        (?<DAY>\d+)()
      ){2}
      \1\2",
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

string input = @"30Jan Feb12 Mar23 4Apr May09 11Jun";
foreach (Match m in r.Matches(input))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", m.Groups["MONTH"], m.Groups["DAY"]);
}
```

This works because in .NET, the presence of named groups has no effect on the ordering of the non-named groups.  Named groups have numbers assigned to them, but those numbers start *after* the last of the non-named groups.  (I know that seems gratuitously complicated, but there are good reasons for doing it that way.)

Normally you want to avoid using named and non-named capturing groups together, especially if you're using back-references, but I think this case could be a legitimate exception.

Comment: It works! Because my A and B expressions contain a whole bunch of groups of their own, I used named empty capturing groups:
X(?:A(?<dummy1>)|B(?<dummy2>)){2}\k<dummy2>\k<dummy1>Y

Comment: Thanks for the additional suggestion. I am using .net, but my A and B strings contain a bunch of un-named capturing groups too (when I create the regex I use RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture). I think using ?: in all these groups creates more clutter than using two named 'dummy' groups. Additional comments welcome :)

Comment: Another cool thing about this approach is that it scales up very nicely! I just had to do a regex that had 3 groups that could appear in any order. It was trivial to extend this solution to 3 groups!

Comment: @Alan: Hey, what about August? 8^)

Comment: @ridgerunner: haha! I hadn't noticed that.

Comment: It's too bloody hot for regexes in August. :-/

Comment: Would there be a way to enforce that each group matches 0 or 1 time?

Comment: AFAIK it works in JS (chrome + FF) as can be tested here https://regex101.com/r/S4uWOg/1

Comment: This is genious!

Comment: @dwelle I tested your example, and it does not enforce mutual exclusion

Answer (score 6):

You can store regex pieces in variables, and do:

```
A=/* relevant regex pattern */
B=/* other regex pattern */
regex = X($A$B|$B$A)Y
```

This way you only have to specify each regex once, on its own line, which should make it easier to maintain.

Sidenote:  You're trying to find permutations, which is ok since you're only looking at 2 subregexes.  But if you wanted to add a third (or fourth), your regex permutations grow drastically - (abc|acb|bac|bca|cab|cba) - or worse.  If you need to go down the road of permutations, there's some good discussion on that here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378397/find-all-words-containing-characters-in-unix/).  It's for letter permutation, and the solutions use awk/bash/perl, but that at least gives you a starting point.

Comment: Sorry, this is not too useful. I use a regex editor to test out the regex, and that's the part that gets unwieldy when repeating complex regex... storing the regex in parts in my program wouldn't help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If there are several strings, with any kind of characters in there, you'll be better with:

```
X(.)+Y
```

Only numbers then

```
X([0-9])+Y
```

Only letters

```
X([a-zA-Z])+Y
```

Letters and numbers

```
X([a-zA-Z][0-9])+Y
```

Comment: No, A & B must match more precisely than that; for example, the 'A' part that I use in my example is actually (s=\s*(?<D>\d*\.?\d*)\s+ and the 'B' part is actually r=\s*(?<E>\d)(/(?<F>\d))?) . That's why doing AB|AB gets kind of hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
X((A|B){2})Y
```

Comment: Sorry, that wouldn't work -- I don't want to allow strings like AA or BB -- only AB or BA :)