# Regex: match optional alternations in any order, not allowing repetitions

Tags: php, regex, alternating

My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596868/regex-matching-against-groups-in-different-order-without-repeating-the-group) one, except that I want to make each alternation optional, and non-repetitive.

Example: The regex needs to match the following strings (this is oversimplified, A and B can be complex):

```
XAB
XBA
XA
XB
X
```

It can NOT match XAA, XBB, XABA, XABB, XBAA

Here is what I have so far:

`/(X)(?:(A)|(B)){0,2}$/`

This allows for repetition (such as XAA), and seems to cause a problem with XB in PHP with an empty array element.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I need to get the actual values of X, A, and B (if available). It's not just a match of the full string.

Comment: You're basically saying that it can't match either `A` or `B` more than once, so why don't you just do a check for that and do away with regex? `if(substr_count($string, 'A') >= 2) echo 'error!';`

Comment: Here's a regex demo if you want to stick with it... http://regex101.com/r/kD2fA1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [negative lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/(X)(?!A{2})(?!B{2})(?:(A)|(B)){0,2}$/
```

**Explanation:**

```
(X)       # Match and capture X
(?!A{2})  # Assert that it's impossible to match AA
(?!B{2})  # Same for BB
(?:       # Non-capturing group:
 (A)      # Match and capture A
|         # or
 (B)      # Match and capture B
){0,2}    # Do this 0-2 times
$         # Then match the end of the string
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way would be to define each group and then use those definition in a certain order:

```
# Start defining
(?(DEFINE)
   (?<X>xrules)
   (?<A>arules)
   (?<B>brules)
)
# End defining
^                    # begin of string
(?&X)                # Use rule X
   (?:               # non-capturing group
      (?&A)(?&B)?    # Use rule A and make rule B optional
   |                 # or
      (?&B)(?&A)?    # Use rule B and make rule A optional
   )?                # make it optional
$                    # end of string
```

Of course, you can change `xrules` with valid regex like `[a-z]+` and `brules` with `[A-Z]+`.

[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/yY8wV4)

Comment: Why doesn't this solution match X, A, or B separately like Tim's does?

Comment: @user371699 Because it's not supposed to. Well you could always wrap some capturing groups, but it will get ugly. You maybe could merge the two answers

Comment: I thought that anything in parenthesis gets captured unless it has `?:`. Why does this seem to be an exception?

Comment: @user371699 Because `(?&A)` is a backreference to the *definition* of the named group `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can have this title: "How to not repeat an optional group?".

```
$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~
    (?(DEFINE)
        (?<X> FOO )
        (?<A> BAR )
        (?<B> BAZ )
    )

^   \g<X> (?: \g<A> (?! .* \g<A> ) | \g<B> (?! .* \g<B> ) ){0,2}   $
~xs
LOD;
```

`\g<A> (?! .* \g<A> )` forces the group A to be present only once in the string, because of the negative lookahead (i.e: "not followed by anything and group A")